# How to optimize a kinetic typography P5.js sketch

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I’m trying to translate a project I made in Processing ([here](https://www.behance.net/portfolio/editor?project_id=69674423)) into a browser version with P5.js. Here’s my initial, [stripped down version](https://editor.p5js.org/full/ryzpqAjKm). It works smoothly until additional rings are added, after which it really starts to slow down and glitch out. And I have a lot of more parameters to add.

There’s a big for() loop for the string of type and rings that draws the appropriate letter and places it correctly in the cylinder structure. Aside from that, lots of push/pop/translate()s and sliders. Any idea how I could optimize it to run smoother?

Comment: As you've stated, large loops within the draw loop are best to look at first. Perhaps update your question with code examples of these. In Java Processing ,I've noticed that when smooth() is enabled (it is by default) any calls to scale() on PImages or PGraphics slows the sketch down considerably.

Comment: Great idea. I hadn't considered turning off smooth. I have lots of scale and movement.